# how to save <httpfile> of video in python server

Tags: python, opencv, tornado

In python tornado server,I got a file of video(like:test.mp4) from client's request. And the type of file is 'tornado.httputil.HTTPFile'.

I want to save it to my server like **'./video/myvideo.mp4'**.
I know opencv [videoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)  may could do that,but didn't use the APIs well.

Comment: You should try to explain what is wrong, what didn't go well with your solution and maybe even put a snippet of code. This may help people to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save files by using Python's built-in [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function, like:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello world')
```

---

A simple Tornado example:

```
class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    # ...
    def post(self):
        for field_name, files in self.request.files.items():
            for info in files:
                filename = info['filename'] # name of the file

                # NOTE: as pointed out by Ben Darnell, if user submitted 
                # filename contains special characters like "../",
                # it poses a security risk. You should generate your 
                # own filenames. See `uuid.uuid4()`.

                body = info['body'] # contents of the file

                with open('video/%s' % filename, 'w') as f:
                    f.write(body)

        self.write('Upload successful')
```

---

**NOTE:** If the uploaded files are large, you might face some problems. Read this - [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/231). You can, however, use [`tornado.web.stream_request_body`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.stream_request_body) decorator to circumvent this issue, although I have neither any experience with that nor a working code example.

Comment: Be careful with filenames. If `info['filename']` contains special characters (like `../`), opening the file may not do what you want, and this is a big security risk. It's always better for you to generate your own filenames than to trust the one the client gives you.

Comment: Using this I get data_received raise NotImplementedError(), any tips?